# Why is __fastcall assebmler code larger than __stdcall one in MS C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cpu-registers, calling-convention

I have disassembled two different variations of Swap function (simple value-swap between two pointers).

1). __fastcall http://pastebin.com/ux5LMktz

2). __stdcall (function without explicit calling convention modifier will have a __stdcall by default, because of MS C++ compiler for Windows) http://pastebin.com/eGR6VUjX

As I know, __fastcall is implemented differently, depending on the compiler, but basically it puts the first two arguments (left to right) into ECX and EDX register. And there could be stack use, but if the arguments are too long.

But as for the link at 1-st option, you can see, that value is pushed into the ECX registry, and there is no real difference between two variations of swap function.

And __fastcall variant does use:

```
00AA261F  pop         ecx  
00AA2620  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],edx
00AA2623  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx
```

Which are not used in __stdcall version.

So it doesn't look like more optimized (as __fasctcall must be , by its definition).

I'm a newbie in ASM language and calling convention, so I ask you for a piece of advice. Maybe __fastcall is faster exactly in my sample, but I don't see it, do I?

Thanks!

Comment: Code size has little to do with code speed.  The __fastcall calling convention is fast because it uses cpu registers instead of the stack to pass arguments.  If the called function is too large and requires the code generator to spill the arguments back to the stack then of course you are not ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, thanks! but you provide me as I understand the classic definition for the __fastcall, but there is also one fact, that calling convention modifiers may be designed differently, because of compiler vendor. So... About registers... I was thinking that large code does seem that all actions are on registers, but if you look at the source code, you can easily see, that stack is using  in the same way for the __fastcall, and there isn't only register use. Thanks for advice, but can you tell me more about this topic please? thanks!

Comment: I really don't care that the compiler doesn't optimize such code. The only proper way to optimize swap is by inlining it. That completely negates the need for calling conventions.

Comment: @MSalters inline modifier could be passed by compiler, so inlining could be not the correct solution, maybe to make a simple __asm() insert with tiny swap function could be the solution? thanks!

Comment: @GeloVolro: Actually, no, that's now how modern optimizing compilers do it. They optimize out the swaps even before assembly is generated, and therefore it's quite common that there are ZERO extra assembly instructions needed. It's instead solved by swapping the registers used in loads or stores, but you'd have those loads and stores anyway.

Comment: Actually, Visual C++ defaults to `__cdecl` unless specified otherwise. That's why Windows API headers [use `WINAPI` define](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21bc8654-3aff-4880-8c9b-5858820e9cbb/winapi-usage-in-function-definition) to force the `__stdcall` convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on optimization, then comparing the results. Your `fastcall` version has many redundant operations because it's not optimized.

Here's output of VS 2010 with `/Ox`.

`fastcall`:

```
; _firstValue$ = ecx
; _secondValue$ = edx
?CallMe1@@YIXPAH0@Z PROC                ; CallMe1
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ecx]
    push    esi
    mov esi, DWORD PTR [edx]
    cmp eax, esi
    je  SHORT $LN1@CallMe1
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], esi
    mov DWORD PTR [edx], eax
$LN1@CallMe1:
    pop esi
    ret 0
?CallMe1@@YIXPAH0@Z ENDP                ; CallMe1
```

`stdcall`:

```
_firstValue$ = 8                    ; size = 4
_secondValue$ = 12                  ; size = 4
?CallMe2@@YGXPAH0@Z PROC                ; CallMe2
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _firstValue$[esp-4]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
    push    esi
    mov esi, DWORD PTR _secondValue$[esp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esi]
    cmp eax, ecx
    je  SHORT $LN1@CallMe2
    mov DWORD PTR [edx], ecx
    mov DWORD PTR [esi], eax
$LN1@CallMe2:
    pop esi
    ret 8
?CallMe2@@YGXPAH0@Z ENDP                ; CallMe2
```

`cdecl` (what you mistakenly call `stdcall` in your example):

```
_firstValue$ = 8                    ; size = 4
_secondValue$ = 12                  ; size = 4
?CallMe3@@YAXPAH0@Z PROC                ; CallMe3
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _firstValue$[esp-4]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
    push    esi
    mov esi, DWORD PTR _secondValue$[esp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esi]
    cmp eax, ecx
    je  SHORT $LN1@CallMe3
    mov DWORD PTR [edx], ecx
    mov DWORD PTR [esi], eax
$LN1@CallMe3:
    pop esi
    ret 0
?CallMe3@@YAXPAH0@Z ENDP                ; CallMe3
```